# Training a really stubborn puppy

Tags: training, puppy

so our puppies name is Ollie. Ollie is an 18 month old American bully mix, with lots of energy to play.

Recently I started working with him more, and he picked up basic commands really quickly, but I'm really failing trying to play fetch with him. He loves to initiate it by bringing a stick inside, and get my attention. I can't get him to drop things through. I used to use another stick to entice him, to let go of his current one, but he's learned this, and now will just chase after the second stick with the first one in his mouth.

I know he kind of understands "drop it." Because he will whine, and usually put a little distance between him and I, after I say it. He is also completely unmotivated from treats, even ones I thought were his favorite. I've also used a digital clicker, but that's seemed the least productive.

From the research I've done, I really don't think he's trying to protect his "claim" as he will usually follow me, and look to me when he gets in a playful mood. I try not to chase him, and will try to "end" the game if he doesn't listen, but I'll throw it once and this process begins anew.

Any help, or recommendations would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Welcome! It qould help to give you focussed answers, if you add some question (question mark) or give one sentence with a clear aim you want to reach. Because this is not a common forum but a Q&A site, this is expected here.

Comment: Not all dogs are food motivated. Sometimes the best you can do is .. just tire them out

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, fetch may not be the best game for your dog and it may be worth looking into other games.

Dogs have different personalities that are very broadly grouped into:

- Socially motivated dogs love to do anything *with you*. They are the dogs that learn commands and tricks easily and tend to always stay close to "their" human.
- Object motivated dogs *love their toys*, chewing on them, fetching them and sometimes guarding them. They don't care too much about who throws the stick, just about the stick itself.
- Internally motivated dogs are the independent ones that might chose to do their own thing regardless of any toys or treats you try to bribe them with.

Of course real life is never only black and white and each dog combines all of these characteristics to varying degrees. If your dog is very object motivated, he might value *having* the stick much more than *fetching* the stick, and *giving the stick to you* might be very, very hard for him. If your dog is more internally motivated he might not care too much about what you want to play, as long as he has what he wants. If he's more socially motivated, he might prefer playing tug-of-war with you than playing fetch.

Our own dog is very socially motivated. We managed to teach her to fetch a frisbee and drop it for a second frisbee to be thrown. It was a long process, but pretty much worked like [Ditto explained in their answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/38546/12501). She still has days where she's more interested in *having the frisbee*. On those days she either drops it much too far away from us, or she does fetch it, but then runs away with it again. Then I engage in a different game with her like tug-of-war or chasing her around the yard. In the end, what matters (at least to me) is that the dog has fun. If playing fetch isn't fun for her today, I can adapt. I'm sure you can, too.

Comment: As far as games go for one of my dogs, "Catch me if you can/try to take this away from me" is the best, most fun, most hilarious game on Earth. Some days I indulge him because he loves it, and it really is hilarious, he's such an imp. Some days I just switch to something else he likes (like learning tricks). As you said, we adapt, to each other.

Answer (score 2):

this might sound odd, but I've read for things like "fetch" .. don't push it, or force him ... ask him to "give it" (save "drop it" for other things) - ask once only ... and if he doesn't, completely ignore him and walk away - game over.
Only continue the game if he actually - willingly on his own - drops the toy for you to play.

Fetch only exists if he relinquishes the toy.  If he doesn't .. no game of fetch. What he's doing is teaching you to play "chase" .. he takes the stick .. and you chase him for it ... his thoughts "THIS IS GREAT FUN!" .. so take that fun away ... you don't want him learning to run from you. ;)

Ironically, this doesn't work well with our dog, as she's quite content to take the toy and chew it on her own (she doesn't run away .. she isn't keen on fetch - although her drop/give it commands are pretty good) ... so YMMV .. :)

but if he's showing interest, it may work that by showing disinterest, he'll learn that to play, he needs to give it up to you.